# Является ли класс POJO обьектом?

Tags: java, pojo

Не совсем пойму в чем так удобен POJO объект и как понять, что он POJO.

По определению это объект, который ничего не расширяет, ничего не имплементирует и не имеет конструктора, все переменные приватные + геттеры и сеттеры... Просто такой себе простой объект.

Значит, если я правильно понимаю, что если допустим выкинуть с этого класса конструктор то он как бы уже POJO?

```
public final class CardFriend {

private String friendName;
private String friendPhoneNumber;
private Bitmap friendPhotoBitmap;
private String friendEmail;
private String Uid;
private int chanel;

public CardFriend(String friendName, String friendPhoneNumber, Bitmap photoBitmap, String friendEmail,
                  int chanel) {
    this.friendPhotoBitmap = photoBitmap;
    this.Uid = "test";

    if (friendName == null){
        this.friendName = States.NO_NAME;
    }else {
        this.friendName = friendName;
    }

    if (friendPhoneNumber == null){
        this.friendPhoneNumber = States.WITHOUT_PHONE_NUMBER;
    }else {
        this.friendPhoneNumber = friendPhoneNumber;
    }

    if (friendEmail == null) {
        this.friendEmail = States.WITHOUT_EMAIL;
    } else {
        this.friendEmail = friendEmail;
    }

    this.chanel = chanel;
}

public String getFriendName() {
    return friendName;
}

public String getFriendPhoneNumber() {
    return friendPhoneNumber;
}

public Bitmap getFriendPhotoBitmap() {
    return friendPhotoBitmap;
}

public String getFriendEmail() {
    return friendEmail;
}

public int getChanel() {
    return chanel;
}

public String getUid() {
    return Uid;
}
}
```

И я не нашел, можно ли использовать логические методы в таких классах? Допустим метод какого нибудь вычисления.

Ну и если кто нибудь приведет примеры, где такие объекты использовать лучше всего (так как не сомнительное преимущество выкинуть конструктор и поставить сеттеры), то будет совсем понятно))

Comment: Вообще, в более широком плане POJO это экземпляр класса, который не наследуется от других классов - Простой Java Объект

Comment: POJO - как правило, объект-модель, служит для удобной группировки разноптиповых данных (других объектов разных типов, как в вашем коде - поля с именем, телефоном, изображением и тд.), чтобы представить их единой структурой (единицей данных, содержащей разнотиповые данные), так же методы записи\извлечения этих данных. Может содержать логику с вычислениями, если это требуется в модели. POJO может иметь и конструктор, откуда ограничение на его отсутствие? тем более, что конструктор по умолчанию создается неявно, даже если его не указывать в коде.

Comment: Тем более не думаю, что POJO нужно искать какое-то специальное применение, это просто характеристика объекта, как, например, тетрадь в линейку.

Comment: Где это есть такое определение? Меня смущает "без конструктора, и все переменные приватные" - я нигде ни разу такого не встречал. Может быть, это какое-то ограничение для совместимости с чем-то конкретным, типа какой-нибудь ORM?

Comment: @m.vokhm я вот тут прочитал... Во втором ответе допустим http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo  и еще где то мне встречалось

Comment: @pavlofff я вот тут прочитал насчет конструктора... Во втором ответе допустим http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo  и еще где то мне встречалось

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, там ниже в комментарии ссылка ни википедию, которая недвусмысленно говорит _** not bound by any restriction other than those forced by the Java Language**_ - т. не связан никакими ограничениями, кроме языковых. И потом выше верно сказано, что этот термин не имеет однозначного и общепринятого определения, он чаще используется просто чтобы сказать про что-то, что это не какой-нибудь Enterprise Javabean или GUI Widget, а простой объект, который мы тут создали чисто для своих нужд, такой, как нам удобно, ни на что не предендуем и отчитываться не обязаны.

Comment: Начнем с того, что официального определения POJO нет. Поэтому каждый сам интерпретирует понятие "простой объект" в силу своего понимания простоты. Кому то думается, что конструктор с аргументами уже не простой объект, я так не думаю. Вообще, в настоящее время за определением POJO-объект закрепилась значение, что это единица данных, состоящая из разнотиповых объектов (как в вашем примере). Такая единица может содержать и конструкторы с аргументами и публичные поля (хотя это и не рекомендуется) и бизнес-логику и [даже наследование](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#customizing-objects).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В докладе Мартина Фаулера, Ребекки Парсонс и Джоша МакКензи от 2000 года, когда впервые был употреблен этот термин, POJO - это просто Java-класс без "наворотов", не завязанный на определенный фреймворк. В контексте того доклада POJO - простые объекты, не являющиеся Entity Bean из J2EE. Четкого определения тогда дано не было, поэтому точки зрения на то, что это такое, могут немного отличаться.

Как правило, такие классы не наследуют от других классов (наверное, можно сделать исключение для классов POJO из того же пакета), не реализуют интерфейсов (иногда делается исключение для маркерных интерфейсов из стандартной библиотеки), не используют аннотаций в определениях и не зависят от сторонних библиотек. Т.е. у POJO могут быть и методы с бизнес-логикой, и произвольного вида конструкторы.

Если делать исключение для Serializable, то к POJO могут быть отнесены JavaBeans. Если разрешить аннотации, не меняющие семантику класса (т.е. без которых назначение объекта и логика его работы не изменятся), то к POJO могут быть отнесены сущности JPA и объекты DTO, сериализуемые в XML или JSON, правила для которых заданы в аннотациях.

Примером того, когда удобно использовать POJO, является обыкновенная модель предметной области в DDD, которую вы сохраняете в БД или передаете через REST-сервис клиенту. Можно напихать в нее кучу аннотаций, а можно - вынести все правила отображения на БД или DOM в отдельные компоненты (конфигурации ORM и сериализатора), уменьшив связность вашей архитектуры.