# Значение понятия Plain Old Java Object(POJO) в Java

Tags: java

POJO (англ. Plain Old Java Object) — «старый добрый Java-объект», простой Java-объект, не унаследованный от какого-то специфического объекта и не реализующий никаких служебных интерфейсов сверх тех, которые нужны для бизнес-модели.
Получается POJO - это понятие, описывающее класс, который не реализует ни один интерфейс и не расширяет ни один класс, имеет только поля, конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры?

Comment: Да, это просто обычный класс.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581808/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы описали - это **Value Object**. **POJO** - это класс, который не использует специальные возможности различных фреймворков, таких как Spring, EJB и пр. Данные фреймворки появились позже и поэтому в названии присутствует слово "старый".

Comment: "это класс, который специальные возможности различных фреймворков" - реализует?

Comment: Скорее `не использует`...

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо. исправил.